# How do you make sure that after sign in the user completes the profile form first before they can use the rest of the website functions.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you make sure that after sign in the user completes the profile form first before they can use the rest of the website functions. I am trying to make sure that after the member has completed the sign up form and then completes there email confirmation with devise that when they sign in that when they are redirected to the new_member_profile_path(current_member) form that they stay on this page and that if they decide to go to a link and click that that they will automatically be redirected back to the complete your profile page with the notice before please complete your profile first. I have it set already once they have completed the form they will be redirected to their member's page. I have looked in multi-forms with wicked - I really feel that because I am still am a Novice rails developer that this would be unnecessary. I am thinking about putting an if clause in the application.html.erb where the site nav template is based and putting a clause with <% if current_member_profile.blank ? %> then redirect back to new_member_profile_path(current_member) with a flash notice tag written in the html file. I have tried this if clause but does not work - comes up as undefined method. Please could someone point me in the right direction or give me the simple solution of getting this idea to work. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Do you have a method current_member_profile anywhere in your application?

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches to achieve what you're trying to do. Perhaps the cleanest with the least amount of code needed would be to first authenticate the user with Devise's own `authenticate_user!` filter and then check for a field that can only be there when the profile has been filled in.

```
# in user.rb
def has_completed_profile?
  first_name.present?
end

# in application_controller.rb
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :require_user_profile

private

def require_user_profile
  # nothing needs to be done if the profile was already filled in
  return if user_signed_in? && current_user.has_completed_profile?

  redirect_to edit_profile_url, alert: "Please complete your profile first!"
  return false
end
```

Notice how I've extracted `has_completed_profile?` into the `User` model instead of putting the name check directly into the controller. This way, if you need to change the logic of what makes a profile "complete", you don't need to touch the controller at all ("complete profile" is a business concept, not a routing/HTTP concept and thus doesn't belong in the controller).

In controllers where you don't want the additional profile check – e.g. the controller where the user actually completes their profile, where they presumably need to be logged in but can't have a profile yet – you just skip the additional filter:

```
# in profiles_controller.rb
skip_before_action :require_user_profile
```

Side note: Over the years I've learned that it's best to keep things like profile data, address data, phone numbers and what not in a separate model and don't extend Devise's `User` model. This prevents various issues and keeps the already huge `User` model (Devise includes dozens of methods into it and turns it into a God Object as it is) a bit slimmer. And if you think about it, it also makes sense in terms of business logic: A user `has_one` profile, `has_one` address (or `has_many` addresses) etc.

Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead for putting an if condition on the `application.html.erb`, You can use a before_action in your application_controller.
Something like this.

application_controller.rb:

```
before_action :check_for_profile_completion 


def check_for_profile_completion
 // your code of redirection to the page if the profile is incomplete
end
```

Also you can skip this action on controller which you don't wanna restrict user to go. Like

```
skip_before_action :check_for_profile_completion, only: [://actions you wanna skip seperated by comma]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new method in the application_controller.rb

For eg

```
def current_member_profile
  current_user.name.blank?
end
```

Check the params which should not be blank when creating a member profile. I have added 'name' here for example. if the params is blank, then it will redirect as you have specified in your application.html.erb